# Unable to use Xdebug with Laradock

Tags: laravel, docker, phpstorm, xdebug, laradock

Tools: Laradock with nginx, php-fpm and MariaDB containers, PhpStorm, Xdebug and Windows 10.

Problem: Whenever I start listening for calls and refresh any page its just hangs, even if there is no breakpoints set on that page. Xdebug starts a session in PhpStorm, but it shows empty.

If I right click a file and start it with debugger I get:

> [docker://laradock_php-fpm:latest/]:php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1
> -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal /opt/project/routes/web.php PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Route' not found in
> /opt/project/routes/web.php:21 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 {main}   thrown in /opt/project/routes/web.php on line 21
>
> Process finished with exit code 255

This is my configuration right now:

[image]
[image]

Xdebug.ini both for php-fpm and workspace:

[image]

Anyone can point me in the right path?

**Edit:** I now get this error:

> Cannot accept external Xdebug connection: Cannot evaluate expression 'isset($_SERVER['PHP_IDE_CONFIG'])'

I think it may be related to the file mapping

Comment: Assuming from the images you're using VSCode and you're installed the PHP XDebug extension by Felix Becker, what does your debug `launch.json` look like? Include that in your question, it will better let us help you.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add the absolute path to the project in the laradock container: /var/www/nameoftheproject

Comment: Where did you have to set this?